# COUNTIF in R That Is Only Applied Once on Duplicate Values

Tags: r

I've been searching for a bit, but can't seem to find a solution to this query.

I have a data frame where I need to find if a unique identifier belongs to a certain month, and then count the times this identifier appears in that month.

A slight twist on this is, that I can only have the count variable show up one time per unique identifier, regardless of how many times it appears within that month.

It should look something like this:

```
 Month   UniqueID  Count
2014/10/1   42         
2014/11/1   68       2 
2014/10/1   68
2014/11/1   42       1
2014/11/1   22       2
2014/10/1   22
2014/10/1   42
2014/11/1   22
2014/11/1   68
```

I think I could get the count, but having it apply to only one row is what is throwing me off here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a roundabout way of doing it, but you could simply calculate the counts first and then merge onto the original data.

Here I used `dplyr`, to first `filter` by the condition, `group_by` the variables, and do a simple count.

```
library(dplyr)
countdf <- df %>% 
  filter(Month=="Nov") %>% # put in your condition for the unique identifier
  group_by(Month, Unique.ID) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())
# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: Month [?]
# 
#    Month Unique.ID count
#   (fctr)    (fctr) (int)
# 1    Nov        GW     2
# 2    Nov        JA     1
# 3    Nov        TJ     2
```

Then to get the dataframe that you want, you would simply merge this data onto the original data, but strip out the information from all rows that isn't the first one in each group.

Here I used `row_number()` to determine whether it was the first entry of each 
group, and `ifelse` to strip out the information if it wasn't the first observation of each group.

```
df %>% group_by(Month, Unique.ID) %>% 
  left_join(countdf) %>%
  mutate(r = row_number(), 
         count = ifelse(r == 1, count, NA)) %>%
  select(-r)
#    Month Unique.ID count
#   (fctr)    (fctr) (int)
# 1    Oct        JA    NA
# 2    Nov        GW     2
# 3    Oct        GW    NA
# 4    Nov        JA     1
# 5    Nov        TJ     2
# 6    Oct        TJ    NA
# 7    Oct        JA    NA
# 8    Nov        TJ    NA
# 9    Nov        GW    NA
```

---

It looks like its something funny playing with `ifelse` and `mutate` with data types. Here is a "workaround" which I think should at least not error out, or hopefully provide you with a more informative error.

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(
  Month = c(as.POSIXct("2014/10/1"),
            as.POSIXct("2014/11/1"),
            as.POSIXct("2014/10/1"),
            as.POSIXct("2014/11/1"),
            as.POSIXct("2014/11/1"),
            as.POSIXct("2014/10/1"),
            as.POSIXct("2014/10/1"),
            as.POSIXct("2014/11/1"),
            as.POSIXct("2014/11/1")), 
  Unique.ID = c(42,68,68,42,22,22,42,22,68)
)

library(dplyr)
countdf <- df %>% 
  filter(month(Month)==11) %>% # put in your condition for the unique identifier
  group_by(Month, Unique.ID) %>% 
  summarise(count = as.numeric(n()))

df %>% left_join(countdf) %>%
  group_by(Month, Unique.ID) %>%
  mutate(r = row_number() ,
         count1 = as.numeric(ifelse(r == 1  , count, 0))) %>%
  select(-r)

# Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
# Groups: Month, Unique.ID [6]
# 
#        Month Unique.ID count count1
#       (time)     (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl)
# 1 2014-10-01        42    NA     NA
# 2 2014-11-01        68     2      2
# 3 2014-10-01        68    NA     NA
# 4 2014-11-01        42     1      1
# 5 2014-11-01        22     2      2
# 6 2014-10-01        22    NA     NA
# 7 2014-10-01        42    NA      0
# 8 2014-11-01        22     2      0
# 9 2014-11-01        68     2      0
```

Comment: Thanks @chappers, I think the second solution you posted is exactly what I am looking for. I'm getting a mix of errors though when I try to mess around with it. Currently, I'm getting this error:

    Error: column 'colname' has unsupported type : POSIXlt, POSIXt

What's interesting about this, to me, is that the column it called out in the error does not appear anywhere in the code I'm trying to run.

Comment: Looks like it would be related to your "Month" variable if it is a date/POSIXt field; a bit hard to debug without knowing more details unfortunately.

Comment: I made some updates to the OP that could be helpful. My apologies again for not including them originally. Let me know what other kinds of info I can provide that may be helpful.

Comment: I have a "fix" but it looks like something weird going on with `dplyr`'s `mutate` and `ifelse`....

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to summarize for each unique month/ID pairing, you could do this as a one-liner with `ave`:

```
df$Count <- ave(seq(nrow(df)), df$Month, df$Unique.ID,
                FUN=function(x) c(length(x), rep(NA, length(x)-1)))
df
#   Month Unique.ID Count
# 1   Oct        JA     2
# 2   Nov        GW     2
# 3   Oct        GW     1
# 4   Nov        JA     1
# 5   Nov        TJ     2
# 6   Oct        TJ     1
# 7   Oct        JA    NA
# 8   Nov        TJ    NA
# 9   Nov        GW    NA
```

Basically you group by the month and ID, and then you return the total number of rows as the first value for that grouping, followed by an appropriate number of `NA` values.

Comment: Thanks, @josilber, but I'm getting errors here, as well. I tried to wrap an ifelse around your solution above to only perform that code on the rows that match my month... the error I get is: "Error in rep(NA, length(x) - 1) : invalid 'times' argument"

Any ideas?

Comment: @gav can you try `df$Month <- as.character(df$Month)` and `df$Unique.ID <- as.character(df$Unique.ID)` and then retry? It sounds like you have a month/ID pairing with no observations, which normally happens when you have a factor with a level that never shows up in your data (perhaps due to subsetting your data frame).

Comment: no dice, same error :/ I also tried as.numeric, because the data I'm working with is number formatted... the ID is a unique ID #, the Month column is formatted as "%Y/%m/1" ... realizing now my initial request should've been more specific to this, I will go ahead and edit that now.

Comment: @gav Well, the code I've posted definitely works on the example data frame you posted (just run it with `df` from the question), so if this code is not working for you then you should update the dataset in the question to be more realistic to your problem. For instance, could you post the output of `dput(head(df))` in the question?

Comment: .@josilber unfortunately, I cannot. The updated edit to the OP is quite accurate to my actual data set. This should've been the initial post, that's absolutely my fault.